# Android - ParseQueryAdapter implement filterable

Tags: android, parse-platform, adapter

I have an adapter that extends [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) and implements Filterable.

I am able to retrieve the results in FilterResults but I dont really know how to publish them. I have an object of this class and I am using that as the adapter for my listview. How can I publish the result into the adapter? I dont have any attributes for this class. Should I make one?

```
private class LocationAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<LocationPost> implements Filterable {

    public LocationAdapter(Context context,
                           ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<LocationPost> queryFactory) {
        super(context, queryFactory);
    }
```

...

Comment: I am having the same issue. I need to implement Filterable and update the List<ParseObject> objects in the ParseQueryAdapter class but it's a private field so I am not sure how to get to it. I looked on GitHub to find the ParseQueryAdapter class but couldn't find that either. Maybe they aren't supporting ParseQueryAdapter anymore? If they are, I want to add filtering to their class

Comment: I am having the same issue. I like ParseQueryAdapter's features and I want to keep it. Let me know if you find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override below method and perform your task

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() { 
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
           // Write your logic for PUBLISHING RESULTS and notify your dataset for change
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
           // Write your logic here to PERFORM FILTERING and return filtered result
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I've done that as I mentioned in the question and I am able to get the results in publishResults but I dont know how to update the adapter and list. How can I notify my dataset there? I called notifydatasetchanged() and it doesnt do anything. I need to populate the adapter with the result somehow.

Comment: I am using ParseQueryAdapter provided by parse. The example you provided is just a general listview.